Convert packet bytes in powershell
I'm using tshark to get packet data from pcap.  I want to know the website url that the tcp.stream is connected to. The only place I can see that will have that is the certificate.  If there's another place let me know, but I do now want to solve this for academic reasons.
I can manually export the certificate within wireshark following http://darenmatthews.com/blog/?p=2036  "Right-click on the on the certificate that you wish to obtain then choose “Export selected packet bytes…” and name the file with a .der extension."
From https://www.c-amie.co.uk/technical/powershell-convert-der-encoded-certificate-file-into-a-base64-cer/ I modified to just present the details.  No need to automate writing files just to read them with  -Encoding Byte.
function CertTextDetail ($certtext=$null) {
  if($certtext -ne $null) {
  $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($certtext)
  $cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new($bytes)
  $cert |select * ; $cert.Dispose()
}}

CertTextDetail $content
    
Subject      : CN=go.microsoft.com, O=Microsoft Corporation, L=Redmond, S=WA, C=US
Issuer       : CN=Microsoft Azure RSA TLS Issuing CA 04, O=Microsoft Corporation, C=US
Thumbprint   : 770170500D521B1E6647DF0949BDC0480613ED80
FriendlyName :
NotBefore    : 9/25/2023 12:26:11 PM
NotAfter     : 9/19/2024 12:26:11 PM
Extensions   : {System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid,
               System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid...}

I see that tshark's first certificate (separated by a comma from intermediate and root certs) tls.handshake.certificate is in raw format and is the exact same data as I see within wireshark's view packet data.  I even did a copy packet bytes into CertTextDetail function and got results. Originally was in ansii encoding.

.\tshark.exe -r "C:\Users\kirt_\Downloads\packetCapture1.pcapng" -T fields -E separator="," -E header='y' -E quote=d -e ip.src -e ip.dst -e _ws.col.Protocol -e frame.time -e frame.number -e _ws.col.Info -e tcp.stream -e frame.time_relative -e frame.len -e tls.handshake.certificate |foreach {$_.replace(' "',' `').replace('" ','` ')}  | convertfrom-csv | where frame.number -eq 1464  | foreach { $_.'tls.handshake.certificate' -split(',') | select -First 1}

308208a53082068da003020......
(note: You have to clean up any quotes within _ws.col.Info or the csv will have bad data from frames with embedded double quotes before convertfrom-csv)
I need to properly convert, encode or decode tshark's tls.handshake.certificate from raw to ansii to match the .DER file so I can use the [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new function and retrieve the cert details.
I spent hours looking for a [system..]::method to do this, but if not done right it doesn't produce the MII... we all know and love.
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIIpTCCBo..

Please help me with the proper method to alter, encode, decode the raw format to ansii.

" I want to know the website url that the tcp.stream is connected to. The only place I can see that will have that is the certificate." - with TLS 1.3 the message containing the certificate is encrypted, so you will not be able to get it. Also, multi-domain certificates are common, so you only know a set of domains instead the real one. Also, don't look at subject/CN, but look at SAN (subject alternative names). A better way would be to check the ClientHello for SNI - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication

Se https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/50476/how-to-extract-a-list-of-server-names-of-all-ssl-handshakes-present-in-log/ on how to use tshark to extract the SNI from the handshake, which is probably both easier and more reliable than what you are trying to do.

Thanks for the tls1.3 info.  I did find a post about that.  I'll look at SNI.  Oh yea I did and it's always null.  wa wa wa

The post seems to be outdated. Works for me with tshark -r file.pcap -T fields -e tls.handshake.extensions_server_name  tls.handshake.extensions_server_name. Note that server_name is not set when accessing a site by IP address or with some clients. But with any HTTPS traffic (except on IP address) it will usually be set since a majority of servers will not work without.

I tried again with slight mod to tshark call and got the SNI.  Thanks for suggestion. Now I'll get the SAN to be sure.

The output from tshark is hexadecimally encoded - interpret each 2 chars as a byte and you'll get the value you're looking for:
$rawCertHexString = "308208a53082068da00302" # truncated for this demonstration

[byte[]]$certData = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $rawCertHexString.Length; $i += 2) {
  $byteString = $rawCertHexString.Substring($i, 2)
  # let powershell re-parse number as hexadecimal numeric literal
  +"0x$byteString"
}

Converting the resulting byte stream to base64 reveals the certificate structure is already encoded correctly:
PS ~> [convert]::ToBase64String($certData)
MIIIpTCCBo2gAwI=

But there's no need to convert it to base64 if you intend to use the certificate data from within PowerShell - you can pass the raw certificate data directly to the [X509Certificate2] constructor:
$cert = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2]::new($certData)

